# Joint Asymptotic Distribution

Tags: statistics, asymptotics, multinomial-distribution

I'm self-studying large sample theory and I ran into a problem. Can someone help? The image of the problem is here.

> **Exercise 6.4** Let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ be independent $U(0,1)$ random variables. Find the joint asymptotic distribution of $[nX_{(2)},n(1-X_{(n-1)})]$.
>
> **Hint**: To find a probability such as $P(a<X_{(2)}<X_{(n)}<b)$, consider the trinomial distribution with parameters $[n;(a,b-a,1-b)]$ and note that the probability in question is the same as the probability that the numbers in the first and third categories are each $\le1$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: What are the definitions of $X_{(2)}$ and $X_{(n-1)}$?

Comment: They are a part of a permutation of X1,..., Xn

Comment: @SMP $X_{(2)}$ denotes (I guess) the [second order statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic), that is, the second smallest value. If you didn't get this, then you didn't get the question. Please make an effort to understand the question (before looking for the answer), and to understand the hint.